# TextBox not updating when variable changes

Tags: c#, uwp

Ive got an issue with a `TextBox` field in my project currently.

Currently, I have a `NavigationViewItem` which is a `SaveButton_ClickAsync`. It opens a save file dialogue and allows the users to input a file name and save this as a `.txt`or `.csv` file.

I have a Global variable that stores the name and file location of the document saved as a string. This varibale then gets referenced across the project.

One example of this is a `TextBox` that displays the `FileName` and `FilePath`.

I have got this to currently update when navigating away from the settingspage and back to the settings page after saving for the first time. It also updates when the document is saved, and then saved again but does not update on the first save without either navigating away from `SettingsPage` OR Saving for a second time.

It does NOT update when i am currently on the `SettingsPage` and save the document for the first time. I need it to do this

I beleive it has something to do with the way the `Private void GlobalVariables_PropertyChanged` is used in the **`SettingsPage`** section below. I have included all relevant code so you can see how it works and the steps the program goes through.

What I need to achieve is that when the file is saved for the first time, `GlobalVariebles_PropertyChanged` HAS to trigger. I feel like i need to be loading in a string automatically into the _fileName/_filePath when the program loads up, this would then allow `PropertyChanged` to determine this as a string change. I may be clutching at straws though. Any thoughts/ideas on this would be great.

The `Get Set` within `GlobalVariableStorage` is a placeholder to allow me to see when the class detects a change.

Heres the code:

**Code Behind**

```
using BS.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace BS.Content_Pages

    public sealed partial class SettingsPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public SettingsPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            GlobalVariables.PropertyChanged += GlobalVariables_PropertyChanged;
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
            GlobalVariables.PropertyChanged -= GlobalVariables_PropertyChanged;
        }

        private void GlobalVariables_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.PropertyName)
            {
                case nameof(GlobalVariables.FilePath):
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(TextBoxFilePath));
                    break;
                case nameof(GlobalVariables.FileName):
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(TextBoxFileName));
                    break;
            }
        }

        public string TextBoxFilePath => GlobalVariables.FilePath;
        public string TextBoxFileName => GlobalVariables.FileName;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName) =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**GlobalVariablesStorage**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;


namespace BS.Data
{
    public static class GlobalVariables
        {
            private static string _filePath;
            public static string FilePath
            {
            get
            {
                if (_filePath is null)
                {
                    return "Document not saved yet";
                }
                else
                {
                    return _filePath; }
                }
                set { _filePath = value; NotifyPropertChanged(); }
            }

            private static string _fileName;
            public static string FileName
            {
            get
            {
                if (_fileName is null)
                {
                    return "Document not saved yet";
                }
                else
                {
                    return _fileName;                
                }
            }
                set { _fileName = value; NotifyPropertChanged(); }
            }

            public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            private static void NotifyPropertChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = " ") =>
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove unnecessary code

Comment: I believe this is relevant to step through the process the save file goes through. The main focus is the **CodeBehind** and **GlobalVariablesStorage** where i believe the error will be occuring. I included the code for anyone that needs to see what the whole program is doing when saving a file

Comment: Hope that is better

Comment: There's an issue where x:Bind sometimes fails with static field. Any reason you are using static class for maintaining these fields? May be you could make these fields in *SettingPage.xaml.cs* and make them public to access them from other places. Btw, here's the issue : https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/19316077-compilation-of-x-bind-to-static-fields-fails-if

Comment: Interesting! Essentially, the class is originally updated from the MainPage. The 'savebutton' writes the string to the 'globalvariablesstorage' class. This is then read by every other class that references the string across the project. I just thought that storing these would be the best approach for my case. I understood it wasnt ideal when i made it but without venturing into MVVM was the best thing i could think of doing :/

Comment: Of course this is the best approach, but since `x:Bind` has some issue with static field, consider using an alternative approach. Btw, If the issue I referred to you is really what is causing the Binding to fail, then I think you are lucky, because when I got into trouble with this, I had to waste a lot of time to come across that issue  :)

Comment: Based on that, I will probably have to re-write a lot of stuff. Thank you for saving me time though. Im not 100% sure if what the thread you linked is 100% my case but it certainly explains a little. I might try populating the string manually on launch and go from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a horribly "hacky" solution but what ive now done is within the SettingsPage cases, done a Frame.Naviate to refresh the page. It works. Its gross. But it works. This only works when you are currently on the SettingsPage and save the file

**SettingsPage** (PropertyChanged case)

```
private void GlobalVariables_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.PropertyName)
            {
                case nameof(GlobalVariables.FilePath):
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(TextBoxFilePath));
                    Frame.Navigate(this.GetType());
                    break;
                case nameof(GlobalVariables.FileName):
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(TextBoxFileName));
                    Frame.Navigate(this.GetType());
                    break;
            }
        }
```